# change the background color of a given field only in a form

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to target a particular text field  in a form and change it's background & foreground color. Likewise different colors for different fields too.

It needs to use css and not js and also there is to be no inline html/code present.

Thanks all.

Comment: Where is the code you're having issues with? If you just want to target a particular field, it's as simple as targeting the `id` in your CSS. There a thousands of tutorials of using CSS on the web. There seems to be no effort to research this, and if you don't post any code or have a specific problem, then this post is too broad.

Comment: I wonder why did this genuine question of mine and a few more of them, genuine questions, got down-voted like this?  I request all gurus or people who down-vote questions to really use their judgement in doing so since it deprives users like me the right to ask more questions. I could not ask questions for nearly 4 to 6 months now? Guys please be more understanding and not down-vote so harshly and that too on questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, Of course you can change the color of particular textbox in html.

Like,

```
<input type="text" style="background:#434343;">
```

Here i have changed color using simple CSS styling. You can change the color dynamically also using JavaScript or jQuery.

```css
#a1{
  background:#123490;
  color: white;
}
#a2{
  background:yellow;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form name="abc">
      <input type="text" id="a1">
      <br>
        <input type="text" id="a2">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP stated they don't want to use JS and they don't want any inline code...

Comment: you mentioned in your code that you can use css.

Comment: But your original answer used inline style - which is not CSS, and you suggested using jQuery...

Comment: i said if you want to change the properties dynamically. I have added the code that don't have inline or any js associated with it. Simple css. Give it a try.

Comment: I know what you originally put - and that's what my original comment referred to. I am not the person asking the question, so I'm not going to give it a try, thanks - hence me pointing out about the use of inline/JS in the first place. The original question is not suitable, as this is a simple search engine search, and this is not what SO is about.

Comment: That's exactly what I asked!!  I think Pirate first showed an inline example of what could achieve that. Then he mentioned that it was also possible to do the same dynamically with js or jquery and finally he did it using the allowed css way. Thank you both.